# Getting "Alpine Expression Error: missing ) after argument list" for function in x-data

Tags: alpine.js

I have a simple AlpineJS component, which is supposed to update whenever a user changes their selection on a select element.

```html
<div 
    x-data="{ timespan: 'TODAY', stats: '' }" 
    x-init="stats = await (await fetch('timespan?timespan=' + timespan)).text()" 
    @change="stats = await (await fetch('timespan?timespan=' + timespan)).text()"
>
  <select class="select select-bordered w-full max-w-xs" x-model="timespan">
    <option value="TODAY">today</option>
    <option value="WEEK">last7 days</option>
    <option value="MONTH">last 30 days</option>
  </select>
  <div x-html="stats"></div>
</div>
```

Now in order to remove the repetitive code in `x-init` and `@change` I would like to move that call into a function. So I extended the `x-data` to this:

```html
<div 
  x-data="{ timespan: 'TODAY', stats: '', updateStats() { this.stats = await (await fetch('timespan?timespan=' + this.timespan)).text() } }" 
  ...
>
```

However when I call updateStats() now I get the `Alpine Expression Error: missing ) after argument list` error. If I replace the `await (await fetch('timespan?timespan=' + timespan)).text()` part with a static value it works fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateStats()` is an async function, so you have to mark with `async` prefix at the definition:

```
x-data="{ timespan: 'TODAY', stats: '', async updateStats() { this.stats = await (await fetch('timespan?timespan=' + this.timespan)).text() } }"
```

Comment: that simple ... thank you!